# How do i call volume from getVolume into isBigbox method?

Tags: java, oop

How do i call volume from getVolume into isBigbox method to write an If statement that checks if Box vlomue bigger than or equals to 500?

As you read in the title I am trying to use the volume in getVolume method inside the isBigbox method to check if the volume is smaller than or equals to 500 in which it will print a statement that its big box else it will show it is a small box

```java
public class Box {

    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private String color;

    public Box(double length, double width, double height, String color) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // Overload constructor 1
    public Box() {
        this(1, 1, 1, "without color");
    }

    // Overload constructor 2
    public Box(double length, double width, double height) {
        this(1, 2, 3, "blue");
    }

    // Overload constructor 3
    public Box(double width, double height, String color) {
        this(5, 5, 8, "red");
    }

    // Standard getters and setters omitted for brevity

    public void getVolume(double volume) {
        volume = this.height * this.width * this.height;
        System.out.println("The Volume of the box is:" + volume);
    }
      
    public void isBigBox(Box b) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the method `getVolume` but it does not return anything (`void`). You should split the methods - than you can call them directly:

```
public double getVolume() {
    return this.height * this.width * this.length;      
}

public void printVolume() {
    System.out.println("The Volume of the box is:" + this.getVolume());      
}
```

In `isBigBox` you can then simple check the volume:

```
public boolean isBigBox() {
    return this.getVolume() > 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make variable called volume in the class Box and make the constructor calculate the volume. you need something like this:

```
 public class Box {
    
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private String color;

    public Box(double length, double width, double height,String color){
        this.length=length;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.color=color;
    }
  
    // 
    public double getVolume() {
        return hight*width*length;
    }
    // 
    public boolean isBigBox(){
        return (getVolume() >= 500); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do that, but instead create a method to calculate the volume on-the-fly. You now have to keep `volume` in sync with `length`, `width` and `height`, which'll become error-prone.

Comment: What kind of errors do you mean? Once the constructor sets the values of the dimension the user sends to it. the volume will be initialized (calculated) from this dimension in the constructor.

Comment: Well, what do you think happens if you call `setHeight`? `height` will change, but then `volume` will be incorrect.

Comment: @MCEmperor Aha, Thanks a lot I got that, I edited the answer. I Wrote the code in that way because there was no setHeight function in the class so I thought that it something will be fixed for this class. But yeah he may change this latter and this new version will avoid this "error"